# Google Maps API V3 - Zoom animation behavior

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to detect and hook into the events "like"
    onBeforeZoomChange and 
    onAfterZoomChange(="zoom_changed")

There is the problem with hundreds of DIVs (labels) layered on the map
and bound to the appropriate markers. When the map animates (zoom-out),
DIVs changed their size twice and then are animated to be smaller.
It seems to be a great performance problem and very poor behavior.
Is it possible to hide these DIVs before zoom starts and show them
in the zoom_changed ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to intercept the methods that redraw the map, but there is a way to intercept the drawing of custom Overlays, because you define the function that draws the Overlay on your own.

The draw-method of a cutom Overlay will be called automatically anytime it is  necessary.

Simple approach: don't redraw the Overlay until the map is idle:

```
  YourOverlayClass.prototype.draw = function(idle) {

    if(!idle){
        var _this=this;
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map,'idle',
                       function(){_this.draw(true);});

        /*optionally you may hide the overlay here*/

        return;
    }
    /**
      * your drawing-instructions here
      **/

    /*show the overlay here when it has been hidden before*/
  }
```

The automatically call of draw will be done without an argument, the suggestion checks if there was an argument provided,

**when yes**: it redraws the overlay.

**When no**: it adds a listener to the idle-event of the map, where the draw-method will be called with an argument(what will redraw the overlay)